# Unable to add attachment to email (Android, Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, email

I have an export button in my app that executes the below code. The email app opens correctly with the subject etc., but it's missing the attachment. I don't seem to be able to get the attachment to work. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
    val filename = "Export.csv"
    val path = context?.getExternalFilesDir(null) //get file directory for this package

    //create fileOut object
    val fileOut = File(path, filename)

    //delete any file object with path and filename that already exists
    fileOut.delete()

    //create a new file
    fileOut.createNewFile()

    //append the header and a newline
    fileOut.appendText("Case Number,Form Type,Status,Last Updated Date")
    fileOut.appendText("\n")

    for (item in arrayAll) {
        fileOut.appendText("${item.number},${item.formType},${item.status},${item.LUD}")
        fileOut.appendText("\n")
    }

val contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this.requireContext(),"${BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID}.fileProvider", fileOut)

    val emailIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO).apply {
        data = Uri.parse("mailto:") // only email apps should handle this
        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Export.csv")
        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, contentUri)
        addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
    }

    this.startActivity(emailIntent)
```

Manifest:

```
<provider
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileProvider"
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
</provider>
```

provider_paths:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<paths>

    <root-path name="root" path="." />

</paths>
```

Comment: Please go through official documents because you need to add some extra code with manifest file and class also as per recent standards. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#ComposeEmail

Comment: First, you should be crashing with a `FileUriExposedException`. `Uri.fromFile()` has been effectively banned for nearly six years. Use `FileProvider` to share files with other apps. Second, `ACTION_VIEW` is not documented to support those extras. Third, email apps do not have to use `ACTION_VIEW` for composing emails. Use `ACTION_SEND`.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks. I'm not getting any crashes! I'll take a look at FileProvider.

Answer (score 1):

Following from you latest comment; According to the [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#ComposeEmail) Intent.ACTION_SENDTO is for when you don't want attachments, I think you need to change this line `val emailIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO).apply {` to
`val emailIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND).apply {` to get your email app to display the attachment

Comment: Thank you. When I use ACTION_SEND, app error with: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND dat=mailto: flg=0x1 clip={null {U(content)}} (has extras) }. When I use SENDTO, app opens Gmail but with no attachment. Why does SEND fail?

Comment: Adding: type = "message/rfc822" seems to fix it.